# An elementary problem related to $Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group,

If $xy\in Z(G)$ then  $C_G(x)=C_G(y)$.

**Note:** Even it is very elementary, I liked it.

**Edit:** Thanks for different solutions, you may want to examine the case if $xyz\in Z(G)$ then what happens ? By using the first result, we can say $C_G(x)=C_G(yz)$ or $C_G(xy)=C_G(z)$. And with a little work, we can also show that $C_G(y)=C_G(xz)$ but what does these relation mean ? If you can explore this case, please add as an answer.

Comment: Please give the definitions of $Z(G)$ and $C_G(x)$. Your answer below does not seem to be correct.

Comment: $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$ and $C_G(x)$ is set of elements which commute with $x$.

Comment: Then what is $x^r$ if $r$ is not a number but an element of, say, $C_G(y)$?

Comment: @Vladimir: $x^r=rxr^{-1}$, I used it as it is almost standart for many sources.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I am accustomed to different notation.

Comment: @Vladimir: you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Let $r\in C_G(x)$ then

$(xy)^r=xy$ as $xy \in Z(G)$ and $$xy=(xy)^r=x^r y^r$$

since $r\in C_G(x)$, $x^r=x$ we have $$xy^r=xy\implies y^r=y\implies r\in C_G(y) $$

And converse inclusion can be done in a similiar way.

**Corallary $1$:** The sizes of conjugacy classes of $x$ and $y$ are equal.

**Corallary $2$:** if $x\notin Z(G)$ then $|C_G(x)|\geq 2|Z(G)|$.

Comment: Corollary: if $xy \in Z(G)$, then the sizes of the conjugacy classes of $x$ and $y$ are equal. (The converse is not true: take $x=(12)$ and $y=(13)$ in $S_3$.

Comment: yeah, you are rigt and when $xyz\in Z(G)$ there are many interesting relation comes as a corolary .(or more than three)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $r\in C_G(x)=C_G(x^{-1})$; then 
\begin{align}
ry&=rx^{-1}xy \\
&=x^{-1}rxy && \text{because $r\in C_G(x^{-1})$}\\
&=x^{-1}xyr && \text{because $xy\in Z(G)$}\\
&=yr
\end{align}
The other inclusion is similar.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter one (but essentially the same as yours):

$rxr^{-1}=rx(yr^{-1}y^{-1})=(rxyr^{-1})y^{-1}=xyy^{-1}=x$. (Parentheses for  clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

The claim is equivalent to $C_G(x)=C_G(xz)$ for $z \in Z(G)$. It suffices to prove $\subseteq$ (consider $z^{-1}$ for $\supseteq$). If $g$ commutes with $x$, then $g$ commutes with $xz$ because $g \cdot xz=x \cdot gz=xz \cdot g$.

Comment: **Corallary:**  $|C_G(x)|\geq 2|Z(G)|$ the elements in $Z(G)$ and
$x^{-1}Z(G)$. if $x\notin Z(G)$